# Retrieve DFRWRT Compilation Parameter

Tags: ibm-midrange

I want to retrieve if a `DSPF` (Display File) on AS400 has been compiled with `DFRWRT(*NO)` keyword. I tried the `QDFRTVFD` API (Retrieve Display File Description), but that API does not return the appropriate information. Is there another way to get this information?

Comment: This is a perfectly good question, and perfectly clear to those who are familiar with `IBM i` and ibm-midrange technologies. It has been put on hold incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find an API, but you can run the `DSPFD` command with `TYPE(*ATR)`, and `OUTPUT(*OUTFILE)`. The defer write flag will be in field `DSWTPT`.

If you run something like this:

```
DSPFD FILE(DFLIB/*ALL) TYPE(*ATR) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) FILEATR(*DSPF) OUTFILE(MYLIB/DFATR)
```

Then you can use SQL to find all the display files with `DFRWRT(*NO)` like this:

```
select * 
  from mylib/dfatr
  where dswtpt = 'N'
```

Of course change the libraries to match your system ;-)